# Connection error using Google Cloud Function and Google Cloud SQL

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

When I launch the following sample code, the first time it works fine. But, if you re-launch it after 1 minute it gives 'connection error' after 5ms.

Two strange things are:

1. That you relaunch before 1 minute it works.
2. If you relaunch it a third time after the 'connection error' it works fine.

Code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const mysqlConfig = {
    connectionLimit: 1,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'mydb',
    socketPath: '/cloudsql/myproject:europe-west1:exampledb'
};

exports.sqldemo = (req, res) => {
    mysqlPool = mysql.createPool(mysqlConfig);
    mysqlPool.query('SELECT * FROM entries', (err, results) => {
        mysqlPool.end();
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(results);
        }
    });
}
```

The package.json contains:

```
{
"name": "sample-http",
"version": "0.0.1",
"dependencies": {
  "mysql": "2.16.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend opening a Support Case for this issue through the [Support section](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/cases?_ga=2.109009222.-559614568.1540805472) of GCP. Reason being that there’s a lot of information that we don’t have access to through Stackoverflow, making it difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: If you don’t want to file a case for Support, some more information is required: is 'connection error' the full error you’re seeing? What do you mean by ‘launching’ the function? Are you referring to triggering it? If so, please specify how are you doing this. I used the code snippet you provided and did not face this issue. What’s the Node.JS version you’re using? What are the contents of ‘package.json’?

Comment: @Maxim, some answers:
    1) If I launch the function using the testing tab it says "Error: cannot communicate with function" and in the log "Function execution took 6 ms, finished with status: 'connection error' "
    2) If I call directly the url it says "Error: could not handle the request"   
    3) Node.JS version 6
    4) the package.json contains: {
    "name": "sample-http",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": { "mysql": "2.16.0" }
  }

Comment: I recommend you to open a new question with the whole issue information/log messages, so it can get more exposure.

Comment: Ok, Joan, I'll make a new round of test and I'll post a new question... thanks

Comment: @UmbertoMigliore In the end did you get to understand what the problem was?